# SQL Max Date Return into Datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I run into an error that states integer is required (got type Column) - From my understanding, the column obviously contains an integer converted time string. Why am I not able to pass the column into the date parameter?

from datetime import date, timedelta

```
maxdate = spark.sql("select year(max(weekenddate)) as MaxYear, month(max(weekenddate)) as MaxMonth, day(max(weekenddate))as MaxDay from starsdata.sep_sdf_shipments_data a")
start_date = datetime.date(maxdate['MaxYear'],maxdate['MaxMonth'],maxdate['MaxDay'])
```

Comment: Possibly because your returned query are columns of the max values.  I haven't used `pyspark` but try `"select top 1 year..."` or use `where...` clause instead (These are the mssql syntax, so I'm not sure if they apply to `pyspark`)?

Answer (score 1):

Without having used spark/a stack trace it seems like this is a type error. spark.sql is returning a Column object which datetime does not know how to work with. You need to get the integer values from maxdate and then pass those to datetime.date

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, the dates are stored as objects even though it is stored as integers inside the query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: After doing research, spark.sql() either needs to be cached with the df.cache() function or parquet with Scala. The object wasn't stored which made it uniterable.